# Will negative-scored duplicates with a zero-scored, non-accepted answer be Roomba'd?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, automatic-deletion

I'm aware that the Roomba rules for dupes are different. For example, as I understand it, a zero-scored dupe with a zero-scored answer wouldn't ordinarily be Roomba'd like a question closed for a different reason would be.

On the other hand, a negative-scored dupe with no answers will be Roomba'd the same way that a negative-scored question with no answers would.

However, what about negative-scored duplicates with zero-scored, non-accepted answers?

Can someone clarify exactly in what situations a dupe will be Roomba'd? I'm already aware of the following:

- A positive-scored dupe will never be Roomba'd.
- A dupe with a positive-scored or accepted answer won't be Roomba'd.
- A zero-scored dupe with zero-scored answers won't be Roomba'd.
- I'm not sure about zero-scored dupes with no answers.

Comment: As a verb, isn't it *roomba*?

Comment: Technically yes, but I'll give him the benefit of the doubt that it was autocorrect who is at fault here.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> Will negative-scored duplicates with a zero-scored, non-accepted answer Roomba?

No. The [Roomba](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba) rules are clear;

- `RemoveDeadQuestions` only triggers when there's no answer
- `RemoveAbandonedQuestions` only triggers when there's no answer
- `RemoveAbandonedClosed` only triggers when it's not closed as a duplicate

Comment: And now I qualify for the secret "posting an answer about Roomba while Roomba is active in the house" hat.

Answer (score 9):

Let's clarify which processes are involved here. If you take a look at the [Roomba](https://stackoverflow.com/help/roomba) article in the help center, you can see that being closed as a duplicate **excludes** the question from the `RemoveAbandonedClosed` script.

Duplicates can instead be deleted by `RemoveDeadQuestions`, for which the criteria are:

> - has −1 or lower score
> - has no answers
> - is not locked

Hence, having any answer at all excludes a question from deletion ([here's an example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45491786/in-java-and-c-why-is-it-if-i-create-a-function-with-a-parameter-and-no-return) of that). Note that `RemoveAbandonedQuestions` works similarly — having any answer *at all* prevents deletion, for better or worse.

Therefore, in answer to your title question: **negatively scored duplicates with answers are not deleted by any Roomba script**.

---

Alternatively, here is [proof by counterexample](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27392596/what-segment-of-memory-are-functions-stored-in). The question is from 2014, with score –2 and one answer of score 0, not accepted. It has not been deleted.