# Should we close a duplicate question as off-topic?

Tags: discussion

I am referring to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48639459/what-does-do-in-javascript) which is a clear duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1049112/what-is-the-meaning-of-symbol-in-jquery) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1150381/what-is-the-meaning-of-sign-in-javascript) several year old questions.

**Why:** If the above mentioned questioned is marked as an off-topic it will be deleted within 20 days (or less). However, the question shows lack of some basic internet searching effort  **but still,** if it were to marked as a duplicate it would have helped future readers who are really unfamiliar with the topic.

- Can anything be done now to revert it?
- Should we necessarily downvote (aggressively) duplicate questions?
- Go through the question comments (initial ones), do they seem like a beginner-friendly approach? Do you really expect world's largest programming site to treat some *basic-questions* / *newbie-user* like this?

Comment: Duplicates aren't automatically deleted, as far as I know. Users/mods have to cast delete votes explicitly. **"Should we necessarily downvote (aggressively) duplicate questions?"** - It doesn't matter if a question is a dupe or not; when it is bad (shows no research), then it deserves its downvotes. **"Do you really expect world's largest programming site to treat some basic-questions / newbie-user like this?"** - Well, it's always the same, the users here are expected to be glad that their time was wasted again and no one cares that these newbie-user treat SO like their personal help page.

Comment: @Tom So, trolling the asker in the comment section is justifiable as they failed to do some proper research?

Comment: The snarky tone in the comments is not the ideal we aim for. But, quite honestly, the OP was setting the tone there. Especially on garbage questions which induce eye-rolling that everyone knows will soon be deleted anyway, people tend to have a bit of fun. Again, not that this is necessarily condoned, but we're all human too.

Comment: @BlackBeard OP failed on many levels, not only the research.

Comment: @deceze Did I remember correctly that closed dupe questions aren't deleted automatically, or am I wrong on that part?

Comment: @Tom Yes, dupes stay to serve as signposts to the canonical question. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/92006/476.

Comment: Side note: anything done or intended "aggressively" is wrong. Luckily we have no tools to do anything of the sorts. For example: you can only cast one downvote. You can cast only one flag. You can cast only one close vote (eventually). You have no tools to persuade or threaten others to do the same. I mean you can try with a comment, but that won't live long. So if for example lots of downvotes happen, those or lots of individual and personal decisions that ultimately congregate to be a very strong signal "this is not good". Quite an elevated and grounded process, really.

Comment: To be fair, if you aren't familiar with JQuery and aren't a native U.S. English speaker (thus unaware that `$` is called "dollar sign") you might have trouble finding a relevant previous question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

> *Can anything be done now to revert it?*

Can? Yes.

But we shouldn't. The question is of low quality. There's a significant lack of research, and it's not a useful signpost for the proposed duplicate target.

> *Should we necessarily downvote (aggressively) duplicate questions?*

No. Duplicates don't necessarily warrant downvotes. However, for this specific example there are plenty of other reasons why it should be downvoted, as explained above.

> Go through the question comments (initial ones), do they seem like a beginner-friendly approach? Do you really expect world's largest programming site to treat some basic-questions / newbie-user like this?

The comments may be harsh / blunt, but they aren't *insulting* the OP. Sure, it's not an optimal (first) experience, but the question wasn't exactly a gem either.

---

The best course of action here would be to delete the question. And thanks in part to the [meta effect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/235225/what-is-the-meta-effect), that's what happened.

Comment: Also, this was hardly a *first experience* for the OP…

Comment: @deceze: Good point. Added `()` ;-)

Comment: "Duplicates don't necessarily warrant downvotes." I would argue that *usually* they do, as failure to find a dupe usually indicates a lack of research. A common example is failing to Google an error message. Not *always*, but extremely often.

Comment: A good rule of thumb is if you can copy and paste the error on a search engine and find it in the first 3 results.

Answer (score 6):

If you don't have a gold badge to hammer, it doesn't matter much to close as too broad or unclear/whatever suits best, even if the question could be answered by a duplicate that you know / just googled for. Close as duplicate if you have time to google for it, but since OP is currently doing zero effort, it's up to you if you want to spend time doing that search.

But, in the case that you have a gold badge that could dupehammer the question, that's tempting to use it just to prevent dumb answers to pour in while the question is still open (and as a nice side-effect it answers OP question, even if OP doesn't deserve it due to lack of research, etc...)

When I choose this path, I try to add a comment explaining why the duplicate applies to this question ([Should we add more explanation when closing as duplicate?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/352439/should-we-add-more-explanation-when-closing-as-duplicate)), we want to be nice, if that doesn't cost too much (last time I did that was there: [How to write a python 3 calculator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48664616/how-to-write-a-python-3-calculator))

Of course, that's a risky bet because if someone posts an answer during the grace period, Roomba does not apply because there's a special deletion avoidance case when the close type is "duplicate" ([Will negative-scored duplicates with a zero-scored, non-accepted answer be Roomba'd?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/360986/will-negative-scored-duplicates-with-a-zero-scored-non-accepted-answer-be-roomb): answer is "No"), so unless downvotes are applied to the question/answer so it can be roombaed/deleted, which is not why downvotes are for in the first place, so it's debatable whether to use them for this or not.

That said, if the question has already accumulated 3 or more downvotes and you have 10 or 20k privileges, you can start the deletion job yourself. 2 more delvotes and the question (& answer(s)) is gone.

Comment: `... best is to close as too broad or unclear ...` Why do you say that? If it is indeed a duplicate, marking it as such will lead the OP and future visitors to the canonical answer, too broad and unclear do not. That may lead the OP to futile attempts at clarifying the question/limiting the scope, despite the real issue being that it is just a dupe.

Comment: @user000001 you have a point. I have edited as I agree!

Comment: @user000001 it does not really matter in that particular case - if OP can't search for title of they question (https://www.bing.com/search?q=what+does+%24+do+in+javascript) then I seriously doubt they going to make any effort to change the post...